# how to pass data from express server to javascript function directly on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to pass data from express server to javascript function directly, how do I do it?

my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">

</head>
<body>
<h1> I want to display message sent by server with js function in main.js, not with <%= msg %> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

my main.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('All assets loaded');
    get_data();
});

function get_data() {
  fetch('./',
 )
 .then(function(response) {
   return response.text();
 })
 .then(async function() {
   console.log("data passed by html is: ")
   console.log(msg) //msg is sent by express server


 });
}
```

my express index.js (using ejs)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render("main.html",{msg:"hello"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script tag to you HTML and render Javascript code:

```
<script>
const msg = "<%= msg %>";
</script>
```

Make sure you add this script tag before your `main.js` script tag. The `msg` constant should then be available globally in your Javascript code.

Although this answers the question, I don't recommend it. If you need to use a value from your backend in your frontend code you should fetch it from an endpoint.

Comment: works perfect! interesting.